# HP Envy Pro 6432 scans every document at a slight angle - how can I fix this?

Tags: windows, printer, scanner

My [HP Envy Pro 6432 all-in-one printer](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-envy-pro-6400-all-in-one-printer-series/29256678/model/33518737) scans every document (be it using the document feeder or the scanner glass) with a 1 degree angle.

At present I use the [Windows HP Smart software](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/hp-smart/9WZDNCRFHWLH) to manually orientate each page by a degree - this is time consuming and causes part of the top of the document to get cropped.

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=hp%20envy%20scan%20angle) offers pages which detail this problem for other printer models and [a solution](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-Copying/Scan-is-Skewed-in-1-degree-everytime/td-p/6946609) involving a "straighten scan" option and disk button. Neither of these exist in my Windows HP Smart software, nor can I find any option to align or calibrate my *scanner* head.

**Is there any way I can get the printer to scan my documents without this 1 degree angle?**

Comment: With the ADF, I would make sure the paper guides are set correctly. But you're saying the platen also skews???

Comment: @hdhondt Yep, even if I align it against both borders, the scan comes out with the same one degree skew. I suspect the scanning bar is at a slight angle but I've got no idea is this is even fixable.

Comment: In my opinion that would need a technician